# anchor tag weird behaviour in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have controller by name"job_classified" the problem is  when i open

```
<a href="google.com"> click me </a>
```

in view it opens http://localhost/my_project/job_classified/google.com instead of google.com

what actually is the problem? i tried other code igniter URI functions but it didn't work for me.can someone guide me how to do it correctly

Comment: you need to provide full url like (`http://google.com`)   because on different browsers link without `http or https` taking project base url and append it automatically

Comment: your link is : http://localhost/my_project/job_classified/google.com so it is open but if you want open google.com then update your url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why your code doesn't work is described here:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/2005097/4248328

So do like below:-

```
<a href="https://www.google.com">click me</a>
```

Comment: @Umeriqbal  glad to help you.:):)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<a href="https://www.google.com">click me</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please change url to:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com"> click me </a>
```

Reason: HTML parses urls as of relative ones if no `http` or `https` is given.

HTML server in your case considers `google.com` as a relative file is the same directory.

Answer (score 1):

In Codeigniter you can do it a couple of ways

Using the base_url from the [url helper](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

***Note:*** the base url in config.php must be set

> https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#base_url

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('job_classified');?>">Some Name</a>

<a href="<?php echo base_url('controller/function');?>">Some Name</a>
```

Also you can use the anchor();

> https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#anchor

```
<?php echo anchor('job_classified', 'Job Classified');?>

<?php echo anchor('controller/function', 'Job Classified');?>
```

> **How to remove index.php from url**
>   https://github.com/wolfgang1983/htaccess_for_codeigniter

Answer (score 1):

Always prepend URLs with double slash. That way you don't need to think whether location should be http or https.

```
<a href="//google.com">This way browser will automatically</a>

<a href="//www.google.com">determine which scheme to use</a>
```